# Unable to override withFixture(test: OneArgTest)

Tags: scala, akka, actor

```
import org.scalatest.fixture.Suite.OneArgTest

class PingPongActorSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("PingPongActorSpec")) 
  with ImplicitSender with FlatSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  override def withFixture(test: OneArgTest) = {}
}
```

When I am trying to override withFixture method with test of type 'OneArgTest' the compiler is giving me following error messages:

1. object Suite is not a member of package org.scalatest.fixture Note: trait Suite exists, but it has no companion object.
2. not found: type OneArgTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mixing in trait "**FlatSpecLike**":

```
class PingPongActorSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("PingPongActorSpec")) 
  with ImplicitSender with FlatSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll  {
  override def withFixture(test: OneArgTest) = {}
}
```

We need to mix trait "**fixture.FlatSpecLike**":

```
class PingPongActorSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("PingPongActorSpec")) 
  with ImplicitSender with fixture.FlatSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll
  override def withFixture(test: OneArgTest) = {}
}
```

This resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use org.scalatest.flatspec.FixtureFlatSpecLike

```
import org.scalatest.flatspec.FixtureFlatSpecLike

class PingPongActorSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("PingPongActorSpec")) 
      with ImplicitSender with FixtureFlatSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your import. `OneArgTest` is an inner protected trait in `Suite` trait, so it can be used in descendants of Suite without import. This 
should work:

```
class PingPongActorSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("PingPongActorSpec")) 
  with ImplicitSender with FlatSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  override def withFixture(test: OneArgTest) = {}
}
```

Comment: object FixtureSuite is not a member of package org.scalatest.fixture

Comment: **project dependencies:** "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.4.4" % "test",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % "test"